# Adding SearchView Widget. SearchManager error

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar

I used this code from the android developing site to implement the search bar, but I get red error lines that says **Unreachable code** and the only fix is to remove the line of code. I am not sure what is wrong here.

```
// Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();

// Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); 
// Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
```

The line that gives me the `errors` is:

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
```

Comment: call this line SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE); in onCreate method and try once.

Comment: But I do have it in my onCreate method. That block of code is all in my onCreate.

Comment: Are you using it in `onCreate` of `Activity`?

Comment: Can you post whole 'onCreate'?

Comment: Are you sure its in activity or onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: I apologize, it was in onCreateOptionsMenu, but if I put it in onCreate I get an error because part of the code calls searchManager

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Place the line
    `SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);` after `return`.

Example: `

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

`